# TableView does not refresh when item was updated or permutated

Tags: javafx, tableview, refresh

I init a `TableView` like this:

```
tableView.setItems(DataModel.getInstance().getData());
tableView.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<DateBean>) c -> {
    while (c.next()) {
    System.err.println("Added " + c.wasAdded());\\false
    System.err.println("Removed " + c.wasRemoved());\\false
    System.err.println("Permut " + c.wasPermutated());\\false
    System.err.println("Replaced " + c.wasReplaced());\\false
    System.err.println("Updated " + c.wasUpdated());\\true
    System.err.println();
    }
});
```

The view does only refresh, If I insert or remove items. An update and permuation does not seem to trigger a refresh of the TableView.

The data list itself does only rarely change, most of the time its elements just update some properties but this does not cause the UI to refresh.

Comment: The columns are responsible for maintaining a `cellValueFactory` that returns an `ObservableValue<T>` for some type `T`. If that value changes, the cell's `updateItem()` method will be called. So if the UI is not updating when a property changes, there is something wrong either with the `cellValueFactory` you are using, or with the cell implementation you are using.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint! I return a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` in my `CellValueFactory`. Going to refactor that. Thanks!